# Configure Jasypt Encryptors using my own SecretKey, instead of setting String password using the 'setPassword' method of the PBEString encryptors?

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I'm trying to configure Jasypt StandardPBEStringEncryptor using the following code.

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor strongEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
strongEncryptor.setAlgorithm(ALGORITHM);
strongEncryptor.setPassword(PASSWORD);
```

And then call the encrypt() and decrypt() methods of the 'strongEncryptor' to perform the encryption and decryption operations.

Is it possible or is there a way I can configure the Jasypt encryptor using **my own SecretKey** instead of setting a password?

Like in Java Cipher, we do...

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, MY_SECRET_KEY);
```

I see that Jasypt internally uses the String password to create the SecretKey and initiate the Java Cipher. Is it possible to provide my Key here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PBE** stands for **Password Based Encryption**.

That means instead of requiring a `SecretKey` it needs a passphrase which will then be used to generate the key by hashing it many times.

So manually settings the `SecretKey` for a **PBE**-encryption would invalidate it's purpose. For exactly that reason `StandardPBEStringEncryptor` does not allow this. (see it's [doc](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html) for more information)

If you want to use your own `SecretKey`, simply use a standard encryption function.